# how it is possible to bold , underline , italic a selected part of text in TextView Control?

Tags: cocoa

Just as I asked in title, I know there were same questions answered but I need in a more simple language with codes, I already browse every question with same topic but all of them explained in an advanced level.
That would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are attributes, and you set them on ranges within [the text view's text storage](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/textStorage), which is a kind of [attributed string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/index.html#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003622).

Both bold and italic are part of [the font attribute](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFontAttributeName), as bold and italic are [font traits](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000383-BAJIIGAD). You can ask the font manager to [add](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFontManager/convertFont%3atoHaveTrait%3a) or [remove](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFontManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFontManager/convertFont%3atoNotHaveTrait%3a) any trait on a font, which will give you a new font, based on the old one, which you can then [set as the new value of the font attribute](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableAttributedString/addAttribute%3avalue%3arange%3a).

Underline is a lot simpler: It has [an attribute all to itself](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName) that you can set or unset.

There's a lot more information in [Font Handling](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/FontHandling/FontHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000093i) and the [Text System Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextArchitecture/TextArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000086i).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cant. If you want to display rich text then its better to use a UIWebView. This allows you to apply any type of formatting that HTML and CSS allows. an example of how to do this is:

```
NSString *formattedText = @"<p>This is some formatted text <strong>Isnt that great </strong></p>";

UIViewView *myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 480.0f)];
[myWebView loadHTMLString:formattedText baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:myWebView];
```

I know it isn't exactly what you wanted, but I ended up using this method in my app 'DevPHP' and it works really well. Because we are loading text into a webview instead of .html page there isn't much of a noticeable delay in the webview displaying the content (which is usually the main complaint when using a webview)

The one last annoying this with a webview is its ugly background image that you cannot get rid of. At the end of the day though, you still get to display rich text and most users wont worry too much about the bouncy webview.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: You certainly can do bold, italic, and underline in an NSTextView. Maybe not in Cocoa Touch, but you can in Cocoa.

Comment: Dear Aron, Tnx for spending time and answering, I found a method to do Bold and Italic... I put the codes as reply.
only left Underline that accept wordMask instead of font mask, I don't know how to apply that... any Idea?

Comment: Its a good point peter, is this a general cocoa question or iOS specific?  I assumed it was based on iOS, sorry for the confusion

Comment: NSMutableAttributedString* text = [txtView textStorage];
[text applyFontTraits:NSBoldFontMask range:NSMakeRange(0,[text length])];